# Find the number of all $6$ digit natural numbers having exactly three odd digits and three even digits.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of all $6$ digit natural numbers having exactly three odd digits and three even digits.

Comment: Please include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: I want the full answer

Comment: [And I want a toilet made out of solid gold, but it's just not in the cards now is it?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHnlKzGbqZc)

Comment: When you pose a question on this site, it is expected that you include your own attempt and indicate where you are stuck.  The reason you have only received a (good) hint is that you have not done that, which leaves the impression that you want other users to do your homework for you without putting any effort into solving the problem yourself.  I strongly suspect that is the reason there are already three votes to close your question.

Comment: I can see that you are preparing for RMO. The questions you've asked so far all come from the same question paper. I don't know what's the purpose of referring to old problem sets, when you don't even want to try.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** First choose the placement of the odd digits in the 6 digits number. There are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to do that. Now just fill the chosen places with odd digits, while the other with even.

You can easily subtract the cases when $0$ is the first digit.

Comment: Can you please give the complete answer

Comment: @user349915 I insist not to. The hint should be enough to solve this question. Follow it and see what you'll get. And you can write the solution here and we can discuss it.

Comment: Please give me the answer as I have tried solving it but I am not getting answer

Comment: @user349915 If you're solving you should be getting an answer, even if it's wrong. Anyway where are you stuck? Follow my hint. What step can't you understand?

Comment: I an not understanding how to place the combinations

Comment: @user349915 As I've told you choose the places for the odd digits. That can be done in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways. Now in those places how many ways are there to put an odd digit? In the other places how many ways are there to put an even digit?

Comment: Is answer 1140 numbers

Comment: @user349915 Not even close.